# MySQL GROUP BY - Erro no PHP

Tags: php, sql-select, mysql, group-by

Tenho uma consulta em MySQL que, na linha de comando e no MySQL Workbench, está trazendo os valores corretos, porém ao executa-la em PHP, a função `GROUP BY` está agrupando mais do que deveria!

Aqui está a consulta:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(ctg.data_de_criacao, '%d/%m/%Y') AS DataMes,
    ctg.assunto,
    COUNT(*) AS InTS
FROM
    registro_atend AS ctg FORCE INDEX (idx_datacriacao)
    INNER JOIN
    registro_atend_ocorrencias AS cto ON ctg.idx_primary = cto.idx_primary
WHERE
    ctg.protocolo_da_ocorrencia > 0
    AND
                ctg.data_de_criacao BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59'
    AND
        ctg.campanha REGEXP 'camp1|camp2'
    AND
        ctg.assunto REGEXP 'card|credit|delivery'
    AND
        ctg.detalhe_do_assunto REGEXP 'analisys|not_delivered|receive_error|password_mail_corrupt'
    AND
        cto.setor_responsavel REGEXP 'credit1|delivery1'
GROUP BY DataMes, ctg.assunto
ORDER BY ctg.assunto, DataMes;
```

No Workbench, a consulta me trás 77 linhas, normalmente. Já no PHP, apenas 9 são retornadas. (usei o `var_dump` após a consulta)

Efetuei alguns testes, e o problema está no `group by`, mas preciso que o resultado saia nesse formato.

Tenho mais de 100 consultas nessa mesma forma, mas somente essa está dando problema.

Como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Troquei o `COUNT(*)` por `SUM(CASE WHEN ctg.assunto = 'xxxxx' THEN 1 END)` e substituí o group por `group by DataMes`, assim, tenho as contagens de `ctg.assunto` em colunas verticais, não em linhas agrupadas.

Vai servir! Mas ainda não entendi o motivo de a anterior não ter funcionado, sendo que todas as outras estão funcionando normalmente e a única coisa que muda é o nome das colunas...

Vai entender!